# Mouse move out in jquery menu , hidding sub menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have http://jsfiddle.net/X8w5M/30/ using https://github.com/kamens/jQuery-menu-aim. Then I want to hide `.listCol` panel whenever I leave my mouse to the other elements in my webpage.

I tried :

```
$("#dropdown-menu").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".listCol").css("display","none");
});
```

But it didn't work like what I want.

Any idea please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $("#dropdown-menu").mouseout(function(){
        $(".listCol").css("display","none");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The js example `http://jsfiddle.net/X8w5M/29/` is breaking.
Reason(from console):
`Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.github.com/kamens/jQuery-menu-aim/master/jquery.menu-aim.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`

Update your example?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this   
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).mousemove(function(e){

                if($(e.target).closest('ul').length<=0){
                   $(".listCol").parent("div").css("display","none");
                }else{
                    $(".listCol").parent("div").css("display","block");
                }
            })
    });
```

Comment: Doing this, I can not hover on the sub menu `.listCol`

Comment: can you please update your fiddle with this code as this code is working at my end

Comment: Testing in jsfiddle is fine but applying in my real project, cannot hover on sub menu. I'm trying to watch each line in my project now. I will let you know how is it after I've done with checking. Thanks.

Comment: I've replaced my code with the code in jsfiddle, but there's still that problem happen (I can not hover on sub menu , because it was hided while I left a cursor from the main menu).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#dropdown-menu").mouseleave(function(){
   $("#dropdown-menu > li > div").css("display", "none");
});
```

Workable link: http://jsfiddle.net/bobkhin/4Ldfs/

Comment: If on mouse leave of `#dropdown-menu` we hide sub menu, so we can hover the sub menu because it is already hided.

Comment: Did you tried my code or check the link? It worked @Domo

Comment: It is working in jsfiddle, but when I implement it in my project, there was a problem as I said above.

Comment: Can you provide the real URL, maybe we can help with real code @Domo

Comment: Hmm it is in my local, not yet hosting.

Comment: Hmmm, it's really hard for us to debug without real code :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47224/discussion-between-domo-and-bob-khin)